# Isabelle code generation for terminating uses of possibly non-terminating functions

Tags: isabelle

Is it possible in Isabelle to generate code for a function `f` that is defined using some recursive function `f_helper` where `f_helper` does not terminate in general but does always terminate for the inputs applied to it in `f`?

For example, I am currently trying to use a function very similar to the following function `f_helper` that performs a powerset construction on a finite automaton - in each recursive step calculating from the set of transitions of the automaton (`transitions`) and a set of states of the powerset construction to consider in this step (`todo`) the transitions in the powerset construction originating from states in `todo` and the states reached by those transitions (the `result_`-parameters carry the intermediate results):

```
function f_helper :: "('a × 'b × 'a) set ⇒ 'a set set ⇒ 'a set set ⇒ ('a set × 'b × 'a set) set ⇒ 'a set set × ('a set × 'b × 'a set) set" where 
  "f_helper transitions todo result_states result_transitions= 
    (let
        new_transitions = ⋃ q ∈ todo . (let q_transitions = {t ∈ transitions . fst t ∈ q};
                                             labels = (fst ∘ snd) ` q_transitions
                                         in (λ b . (q,b, (snd ∘ snd) ` {t ∈ q_transitions . (fst ∘ snd) t = b})) ` labels);
        result_transitions' = result_transitions ∪ new_transitions;
        result_states' = result_states ∪ todo;
        todo' = ((snd ∘ snd) ` new_transitions) - result_states'
      in 
        if todo' = {} 
          then (result_states', result_transitions')
          else f_helper transitions todo' result_states' result_transitions')"
```

This function does of course not terminate for arbitrary inputs (e.g. if `transitions` is infinite and allows infinite paths that do not visit any state twice), but it does terminate if the arguments are finite and it should be easy to prove any use of `f_helper` to be terminating if additionally the initial `todo` is a subset of the powerset of the state set of the automaton and the initial `result_`-sets are empty, as in this case each recursive step must insert some new element into `result_states` while this set is also a subset of the (finite) powerset of states of the automaton.

Consider then the following function `f` that uses `f_helper`, where functions `transitions` and `initial` respectively extract the finite set of transitions and the initial state of automaton `a`:

```
fun f :: "('a,'b) automaton ⇒ 'a set set × ('a set × 'b × 'a set) set" where 
  "f a = f_helper (transitions a) {{initial a}} {} {}"
```

I would like to be able to generate code for `f` even though I cannot prove termination of `f_helper` in the general case but only for certain assumptions on the parameters (which are satisfied in `f`).
I know that I could probably ensure the assumptions by checks in `f_helper`, but I believe that this would lead to very inefficient code.

Is there a way to define the recursive function `f_helper` only within the context of `f` to avoid having to prove termination of `f_helper` for inputs that are not relevant (infinite sets etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function `f_helper` is tail-recursive, you should be able to define `f f_helper` via `partial_function` as follows:

```
partial_function (tailrec) f_helper :: ... where 
  [code]: "f_helper transitions todo result_states result_transitions = ..."
```

Then afterwards `f_helper` should be amenable for code-generation.

Best,
René

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful, as I had learned about `partial_function`, but did not know exactly what to do with it.